# Multiple root bones found error

Tags: rigging, bones, unreal-engine

I have a question about rigging.
I try to make a player character in blender to export to FBX (to use in the Unreal Engine).
However every time I try to import it in Unreal Engine I get an error that my skeleton contains multiple root bones.
I really don't get why it's saying that, I can only find one root bone.
So my question is: Is there a command or something where it will tell me how many root bones my skeleton has and witch bones are root bones? 
(normally I would try to delete my skeleton and start all over but this model cotains 306 bones, so yeah.... I rather try somethings else first ;p)

Thx in advance for reading and thinking! :)

Comment: I faced the same problem, and I had to debug the unreal engine code to understand what he was doing. I describe the process here to solve the issue. This is for 3dsmax, but the concept is the same also in Blender. http://planeshift.top-ix.org/pswiki/index.php/Import_a_char_3DSMAX

Answer (score 1):

You can check it in the Outliner. After you open the armature's hierarchy you can see how many bones are directly below of the armature. The "left" has two root bones, the "right" has only one. So if you click on the triangle near the armature data and you see more than one bone immediatelly, then you have multiple root bones.
[image]